# how can I use the exec function in PHP on a specific user

Tags: php

By default when `system()` and `exec()` functions are used in PHP the default user is SYSTEM so I can never see the result. Is there a way to change the user it runs on?

Comment: exec() will be run as the user that started the process (like apache). That cannot be changed. However, exec() should return the result of the command.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing what operating system you use (and whether you're likely to change). Although I believe that there's a sudo like tool for Microsoft (sudowin)

Comment: I am using Windows 7 with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

To addon to webbiedave, you can output or save it to a file.
My recommendation would be to save it to a database if you can, this will prevent a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

The web server may have provisions for running scripts as another user (e.g. suEXEC), but PHP itself cannot do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a cronjob (specific user), that checks a file every minute. With PHP (other user) you can write to this file. If the cronjob find something in the file, it starts processing the task under a specific user. That's is the only way IMHO to change the user.